# AngularJS unit test controller with $locationChangeStart in it

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I'm new to AngularJS Unit testing. I want to test a function in a controller with jasmine. In the same controller there is also a watch for $locationChangeStart

```
$scope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function(){
    $scope.killTimer($scope.timer);
});
```

I **do not** want to test this, but another function. Still when I try to run a test, I get an error, which points to the $scope.$on line:

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

What should I do to make the test not run this line? I copy my test spec because I'm not sure if everything is OK there.

```
describe('invoiceListController', function() {
    beforeEach(module('invoice'));

    var $controller;

    beforeEach(inject(function(_$controller_){
        // The injector unwraps the underscores (_) from around the parameter names when matching
        $controller = _$controller_;
    }));

    var $scope, controller;

    beforeEach(function() {
        $scope = {};
        controller = $controller('invoiceList', { $scope: $scope });
    });

    describe('deleteInvoices()', function(){
        it('should do nothing when no invoice is selected', function() {
            $scope.invoicesToDelete = false;
            var response = $scope.deleteInvoices();
            expect(response).toEqual(false);
        });
    });
});
```

And the code I want to test:

```
$scope.deleteInvoices = function(){
    if($scope.invoicesToDelete) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
};
```

Example in Plunker: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/pY4UZsNEm8fTPkJIT4oJ?p=preview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current tests wouldn't actually run through scope at the moment as you would need to $apply after setting and running scope functions. This will not fix your undefined problem though, check that the function you have written is available to your test ($scope.killTimer). Likely hood is that it will be something in the killTimer function that is erroring.

i.e.

```
it('should do nothing when no invoice is selected', function() {
            $scope.invoicesToDelete = false;
            var response = $scope.deleteInvoices();

            $scope.$apply();
            expect(response).toEqual(false);
        });
```

**UPDATE**
After looking at your plunkr it is actually your scope implementation in the test that was wrong, by fixing this the whole test case worked as expected.

```
$scope = $rootScope.$new();
```

Is what you should inject into your controller to implement scope properly. I have updated your plunker here.
http://plnkr.co/edit/p3LShkxT12B1qw7fNbEb?p=preview

Comment: $scope.killTimer should be available, though it shouldn't matter because it shouldn't be called in the first place. But I tried to include the $scope.$apply() in the test code, and know it says that also undefined. I think I'm missing something in the preparation of the test but couldn't found out what. (the app's name is 'invoice', and the controller's name is 'invoiceList')

Comment: I would set up a jsfiddle for us so we can see the whole controller and test together then I can take a proper look, without seeing everything it might be difficult.

Also, locationChangeStart maybe firing as the initialisation of your controller.

Comment: I added a plunker example to the question.

Comment: @Cathfaern fixed it for you in my answer above